# Is Flutter web support aimed only for implementing application-like websites?

Tags: flutter, web, copy-paste, flutter-web

At the moment [Flutter web support](https://flutter.dev/web) is available in the beta channel. If you test [Flutter web demos](https://flutter.github.io/samples/#?platform=web) you may notice that selecting and copying text into clipboard isn't possible.

However, this is how mobile applications work. In the Amazon mobile application you can't select and copy all the text elements. In the Amazon website you can.

So, is Flutter web support aimed only for implementing application-like websites (like games, visualizations, utilities etc.) or will it be good also for implementing content oriented websites (like stackoverflow.com for example)?

Comment: Your distinction between "application-like websites" and "other kinds of websites" is arbitrary. As far as I'm concerned, StackOverflow **is** an "application" website.

Comment: I opened a few Flutter demos in the DOM inspector of my browser and I was horrified at what I was looking at. The Flutter web-engine seems to be generating hundreds (thousands?) of custom DOM elements to represent Flutter's visual primitives - which of course means that Flutter is fighting the web rather than embracing it, so it's no wonder things like text-selection don't work. It's like rendering a web-page using a `<canvas>` or like using a giant SVG image or PDF as a web-page. Based on this experience I'd strongly recommend avoiding Flutter's web engine entirely.

Comment: I changed "other kinds" to "content oriented".

Comment: Yeah - I get where you're coming from: HTML+CSS's content model is geared around text content and "boxes" rather than being about facilitating a truly custom UI built around composable components without CSS's decades-old constraints on layouts and rendering - but with modern CSS4+ layout features there's very little that's still impossible in CSS. Overall, I think Flutter-for-Web is a cool demo but with very little staying-power. And Google drops popular projects all the time... I'd hate to be someone who has to maintain a legacy internal business Flutter app in 5 years time.